# Combine count group by queries into single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table like this (in fact SuccessFlag is more complicated)

```
AccountId SubaccountId SuccessFlag Count
10        1            true        5
10        1            false       1
10        2            true        6
10        2            false       2
21        1            true        7
21        1            false       3
21        2            true        8
21        2            false       4
```

and need a query that will form such a table

```
AccountId SubaccountID Failed Total
10        1            1      6
10        2            2      8
21        1            3      10
21        2            4      12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
SELECT AccountId, SubaccountID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SuccessFlag = 'false' THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,
    SUM([Count]) AS Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY AccountId, SubaccountID
```

Comment: No,
I need Total to be calculated as sum of count for each account-subaccount pair.

Comment: Which is exactly what my example does, as I'm using GROUP BY on account and subaccount.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15fa8/1